# CPU usage at 100% but tasks using it are not showing

Tags: windows-10, cpu

My CPU usage is at 100%, but when I open task manager, there are no tasks using 100% of its processing power. This is what I mean:

[image: Task Manager]

I've sorted the apps in descending order of CPU usage. Adding them up gives 3.9, but the tab heading reads 100%. And it is actually at 100% - the PC is slow that I can't even scroll this page smoothly.

The problem lasts for about 5 minutes, but I experience it several times per day.

I am very sure some other apps are using the CPU, but why can't I see them? I am running an admin account, and I have no other users.

Comment: Only the “Details” view will show everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task Manager > under Performance tab > open Resource monitor and check under CPU tab. You will see cpu process utilization.

Comment: Now it is back to normal, I will check when it goes to 100% again. Thank you.

Comment: @WaisKamal sure

Comment: Yes, I can see the processes using my CPU there, but why? Is this a windows bug?

Comment: @WaisKamal No this is not the bug. Event in previous versions of windows (win 7, 8), resource monitor is available, same location you will find it.

Comment: No, I also couldn't see there which process is eating so many resources. Win10.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you are running an admin account. Those can be processes from another user. failing that, I'd wager you've got a virus.

Comment: I am running an admin account and I am the only user. And if I've got a virus, shouldn't it show in the task manager?

Comment: Unfortunately modern viruses are fully capable of hiding themselves from Task Manager. And it isn't particularly difficult.

Answer (score -1):

1) yes, if and when windows 10 is installed on a older-hardware this happens randomly.
say on intel chips before 6th gen i3/i5/i7. you could address this by using process governor tools like bitsum process lasso.

2) you can update all the drivers to their latest by using iobit driver booster and see that it works ( when windows auto driver update fails )

3) if both above doesn't work, stick with Windows 7 SP1.